# How to with controller make link like /{Country}/{city in this country}/

Tags: java, spring, controller, spring-data-jpa, mapping

I use a controller in my application. I used @RequestMapping, but I cannot solve this problem with it: suppose
I have a table with a list of countries in my database, and a table with a list of cities (a country is connected one to many with cities). how can I make sure that when I click on a country, I go to the list of cities of this country, and the link was like / Russia / Moscow
p.s. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PathVariable`.

```
@GetMapping("{country}")
public List<String> getCities(@PathVariable String counrty);
```

to get list of cities by country, and another

```
@GetMapping("{country}/{city}")
public String getCity(@PathVariable String counrty, @PathVariable String city);
```

to get city info.

Answer (score 0):

Following good endpoint construction practices should be like this:

```
@GetMapping("/countries/{country}/cities")
public ResponseEntity<?> listCitiesByIdCountry(@PathVariable long country) {
     //Code for get Cities for that idCountry
     return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
}
```